# Pre-install Azure-cli on an Ubuntu VM using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using Terraform to deploy an Azure VM. I want to explore the option of pre-installing a bunch of tools like the azure cli on the VM once it is created in the cloud.
Can someone help me with an example on how that can be achieved?
My current terraform script looks like:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                            = "trainingVM-1"
  resource_group_name             = data.azurerm_resource_group.current.name
  location                        = data.azurerm_resource_group.current.location
  size                            = "Standard_B2s"
  admin_username                  = "vmsysuser2"
  admin_password                  = "Training123!"
  disable_password_authentication = false
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.linux.id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  identity {
    type         = "SystemAssigned, UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.uai.id]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1/ You need to add this to your ***azure VM*** resource block:

```
custom_data = filebase64("azure_cli.tpl")
```

2/Then create the file "azure_cli.tpl" with the linux instructions to install Azure CLI:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install azure-cli -y
```